# strange behaviour with pdo mysql latitude longitude conditions

Tags: mysql, pdo, geospatial

I have a pdo query to search for places within a NE SW square/grid it seems to return stray results that shouldn't match the condition.

```
$query ="SELECT id, COUNT(id) as records, geohash, lat, lng FROM places";

$query .=" WHERE
(:latMax  < :latMin AND lat BETWEEN :latMax  AND :latMin) || (:latMax  > :latMin AND lat BETWEEN :latMin AND :latMax ) 
 AND
 (:lonMin < :lonMax AND lng BETWEEN :lonMin AND :lonMax) || ( :lonMin > :lonMax AND lng BETWEEN :lonMax AND :lonMin)";

 $query .= " Group By geohash"; 

 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

 $stmt->bindParam(':latMin', $latMin);
 $stmt->bindParam(':latMax', $latMax);
 $stmt->bindParam(':lonMin', $lonMin);
 $stmt->bindParam(':lonMax', $lonMax);

 $result = array();
   if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
 }
```

For Example if

```
$latMax =43.8573636288909;
$latMin = 43.360191211239965;
$lonMax = -78.53449632050786;
$lonMin =-80.81827927949223;
```

It will return correct resutlt plus some stray results, in this example it returns a place with lat: 55.871751500000  and lng:-4.288359800000

Which should fall outside the bounds of the where statement?

Is their a glaring reason why this would happen?

Comment: Does this work `WHERE lat BETWEEN :latMin AND :latMax AND lng BETWEEN :lonMax AND :lonMin`?

Comment: that doesn't work for both hemispheres of the globe